# Strange delay with alert in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I have some `UITableView` with data from internal `array`. I want to show `UIAlertController` on tap but I'm experiencing very strange delay.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("tapped \(dispatcher.conversations[indexPath.row].name)") //this one works fine, no problems here

    let message = dispatcher.conversations[indexPath.row].desc + "\n\nDo you wanna play this?"
    let alertname = dispatcher.conversations[indexPath.row].name

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertname, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "Play", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        //play the file
    })

    let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { (action) in
        //cancel the file
    })

    alert.addAction(actionOK)
    alert.addAction(actionCancel)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        //some code here
    })
```

My first alert has some delay, but it is mostly ok. But if I'm trying to tap the next cell, I have to wait several seconds for my alert to show.

So, it seems I don't have any problems with access to my data (print works just fine), but somehow it needed several seconds to show UIAlertController after that.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you testing it in Device or in Simulator ?

Comment: both (with the same results).

Comment: Can you try it without plugin in device.

Comment: actually we already have the right answer below. i tried this, it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Present it on your main queue instead:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
    //some code here
    })
})
```

Comment: wow. thanks!
i will accept your reply as an answer in 9 minutes

Comment: Great, glad to help @lithium